# How to make a card in Bootstrap 5?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am a back-end developer and now I need to work a little with the front). You need to make a card so that it looks like this
[image]

But I get something like this
[image]

I can't align the text to the center of the block, because the picture interferes.
My code looks like this:

```
<div class="row ms-1 me-1 card rounded-3 mt-3" >
      <div class="d-flex align-items-center col-12">
            <div class="float-start ">
                <img class="rounded-3" src="{{$link->photo}}" style="width:50px;">
            </div>
            <div class="text-center">
                <h4 class="mt-1">{{$link->title}}</h4>
            </div>
      </div>                        
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a h-100 class

```
<div class="row ms-1 me-1 card rounded-3 mt-3" >
      <div class="d-flex  h-100 align-items-center col-12">
            <div class="float-start ">
                <img class="rounded-3" src="{{$link->photo}}" style="width:50px;">
            </div>
            <div class="text-center">
                <h4 class="mt-1">{{$link->title}}</h4>
            </div>
      </div>                        
</div>
```

Comment: It is necessary that the text be horizontally aligned on the block

Comment: Do the same thing - add a `w-100` and `justify center` or whatever the equivalent in bootstrap is.  @ШайтанЯкубович

Comment: In general in flexbox when you specify vertical or horizontal centering you need to also specify the width or height as a general rule.